# 'r' in Python commands

Tags: python

This has probably answered somewhere at sometime but the titles I have seen don't connect so here it goes.  I have seen python commands that read `os.listdir(r".\bootstrapper")`.  What is the `'r'` doing?

Cheers...

Answer (score 6):

it prevents the Python interpreter from attaching any special meanings to special characters in the string (such as the backslash), and just interpret it as is (i.e., in its "raw" form). This is one way  you can "escape" special characters in strings you use.

You'll often see raw strings in path specifications.  Let's say the path contains a directory that starts with t, e.g., `c:\tests\data.csv`, so you'd not want `\t` to be interpreted as a tab, hence use the `r` modifier.

Comment: Slightly nitpicky, but note that Python doesn't attach special meaning to the *string*, but to the backslashes (escape sequences) within the string literal.

Comment: @benhoyt So noted, I'll update my explanation to be more precise - thanks

Comment: @user466740 Just a friendly note, if this solved your problem, please consider [**accepting this
answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)
by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer. It'll mark this
problem as solved, and reward both of us with some rep points - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

r marks raw input. This means that the normal escape characters within the string are ignored (like \ )

Answer (score 2):

It's a *raw string* which removes the special nature of backslash.

[Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: Good idea to reference -- but you've linked to the `re` module rather than the documentation about [string literals (including raw strings)](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

It makes it a raw string.  In other words, backslashes will be preserved.  `'\n'` is interpreted as a new-line, but `r'\n'` is interpreted as the literal characters '\' and 'n'.

Also note that occasionally you'll see `u'string'` if you're using python2.x code.  This implies that the string should be interpreted as a unicode string.  (in python 3.x, all strings are interpreted as unicode)

Comment: Python 3.3 will allow the `u` unicode indicator (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/), making one less thing to worry about when porting 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

`r` means `raw input`. If a string is marked as `r`, then the meaning of any special character whithin the string will be ignored, the most frequently situation will be the `backslash`.